# How do I Pass and use a Custom Class to an RDLC report?

Tags: c#, reportviewer, rdlc

So I have a class called CustomClass1 which has several string and DateTime properties. I'm passing an instance of another class to an RDLC that has, amongst other things, several properties of type CustomClass1.

in the RDLC I am configuring the Dataset field as below:

```
   <DataSet Name="ExtensionRequestFormViewerModel">
     <Fields>
       <Field Name="SomeField">
         <DataField>SomeField</DataField>
         <rd:TypeName>FullyQualifiedNameSpace.CustomClass1</rd:TypeName>
       </Field>
       --- Other Fields
     </Fields>
   </DataSet>
```

I can see the property is populated in the data being sent to the RDLC, but when I try to read the data as below:

```
<Value>=Fields!SomeField.Value.Property1</Value>
```

I get an #Error in the FormViewer

is there a specific way of registering and handling custom classes in RDLC reports?

Thanks

Stewart

Answer (score 3):

No responses, but I worked it out. If I made the CustomClass1 class serializable the RDLC was able to deal with the class.

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks. (You should accept this as the correct answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Say I have a custom class that holds some data like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class AppTelecommunicationsNumber : AppContactMechanism {
    public int AreaCode { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public int? CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Extention { get; set; }
}
```

Say I want to display the `ContactNumber` field on a report. You must add the `[Serializable]` attribute to your class before you can reference it in the expression editor in the RDLC designer.

You can then reference the fieldname directly like this:

```
=First(Fields!PhoneNumber.Value.ContactNumber, "WorkOrderViewModel")
```

FWIW: I had written hundreds of reports before I figured this out.